# Need to make this recursive algorithm iterative due to stack overflow

Tags: recursion

Basically I have this huge function in Python (which I've simplified to the bare basics)

```
def rec(a,b):
  if stoppingCondition==True: return 1

  key=(a,b)
  if key in memo: return memo[key]

  if b==side condition:
       memo[key]=rec(a+1,b)   #RECURSIVE CALL
       return memo[key]

  total=0
  for d in D:
      if condition1==True:
          b=some process 1
          total+=rec(a+1,b)   #RECURSIVE CALL
      elif condition2==True:
          for x,y in d:
              if (some break condition==True): break
          else: #only gets called if break didnt happen
              b=some process 2
              total+=rec(a+1,b)   #RECURSIVE CALL
   memo[key]=total
   return memo[key]
```

And I am having a heck of a time making it iterative because it blows up for deeper recursive levels. I've already read up other threads about converting to loops and stacks and whatnot but I just can't get any of it working.

Comment: I am trying a stack approach btw

Answer (score 1):

You can always calculate `rec(a, b)` for all `b`, starting at the highest `a` and decreasing in a simple loop without recursion. Now, this solution is not viable if the traversal of all possible calls to `rec()` is sparse, since it will introduce a lot of unnecessary calculations.

Another solution is to try to implement tail-call optimization in Python. I haven't tried it, but you might want to test [this decorator](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/474088/).

A less elegant solution is to increase the recursion limit to fit your need:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(10000)
```

Comment: I tried the setrecursionlimit thing and it wasn't enough unfortunately. The decorator you posted also does not work properly (my function returns the wrong values). Not sure what you mean about looping for all b starting at highest a.

Comment: Did you try increasing the values of the `setrecursionlimit`? What happened when you increased it a lot? If you know the maximum value of `a`, then you can start calculating the value at the maximum `a` for all `b`, and so forth.

Comment: When I call my function from main() I do it with a=0 and b=list of 0's.

Comment: I am trying a stack approach and not getting anywhere... how do I take into account the stop condition?